# Rings such that all quotients by prime ideals are PIDs?

Tags: terminology, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring such that for every prime ideal $P$ of $R$, the ring $R/P$ is a PID. Do you know how these rings are called or another characterization of them?

I know there are a lot of examples of this kind of ring, for example every commutative Artinian ring. But I am trying to characterize these rings.

Comment: Do you actually mean the quotient or rather the localisation? Also, you may want $P$ to be non-zero otherwise at least for a domains $R$ ought to be a PID.

Comment: I am going to characterize commutative rings R s.t. for every prime ideal P of R, R?P is a PID. I know there are a lot of examples of there kind of rings. For example every commutative Artinian ring. But I am trying to characterize these rings. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, if R is a Dedekind domain, then all ideals are one-and-a-half generated.  So, if P is a (non-zero!) prime ideal, the quotient ring R/P must
be a PID.

Comment: Thanks. I know there are a lot of rings with this condition. As you said Dedekind domain, for each nonzero prime ideal P of R, R/ P is a PID. Or as another example if R is a commutative Artinian ring, then for every prime ideal P we have R/P is a field. But I need to obtain a {\bf characterization} for commutative rings s.t. for every prime P, R?P is a PID .

Comment: What does one-and-a-half generated mean?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg it means that you can complete *every* non-zero $i \in I$ to some two element generating set of $I$.

Comment: @quid:  Thanks! $\phantom{xxxxxxxxxxxxxx}$

Comment: Note that the parenthetical "(non-zero!)" is actually important, as it rules out most Dedekind domains having the property Najmeh wants.